# Can someone explain the process of passing by value/reference of this code?

Tags: c++

```
void Twist(int a, int& b)
{
    int c;

    c = a+2;
    a = a*3;
    b = c+a;

}
```

What is the output of the following code fragment involving Twist(all variables type int)?

```
r = 1;
s = 2; 
t = 3;
Twist(t,s);
cout << r<< ''<< s<< ''<< t<< endl;
```

I know this displays 1, 14, 3 but why?

Comment: Please do the math yourself (without down-vote)

Comment: does it really give 1,14,13??

Comment: Why don't people run the code and step through the debugger to see what is happening?  It is such a useful skill to learn they should teach that before they even go over writing code.

Comment: Please show the actual output. There are no commas in your `cout` statement so it can't be "1, 14, 13".  It's the 13 that I'm skeptical about. It should have output "1 14 3".

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: What's this _`cout << r<< ''<< s<< ''<< t<< endl;`_ actually supposed to be? Fix your quote characters please! It should be: `cout << r << ", " << s << ", " <<  t<< endl;`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

When you pass something by value (as you pass the first variable in function) a **copy** of that variable is born!

On the other hand when you pass something by reference the **actual** variable gets into the function.

In your example, you pass a copy of a but the actual b. So when you get out of the function the `t` has not changed while `s` which is passed by reference is changed.

```
void Twist(int a, int& b)
{
    // a is 3 and b is 2
    int c;

    c = a+2; // c = 3 + 2 = 5

    // CAREFUL: This is not the actual t you passed. It is a copy.
    a = a*3  // a = 3 * 3 = 9.

    // THIS IS the actual s you passed. NOT a copy.
    b = c+a; // b = 9 + 5 = 14

    // Now when you get out the value of s is updated to 14
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `twist(t,s)`:

`r` is `1` because it never changes.

`t` is `3` because it is passed by **value** into `Twist`, so it never changes.

`s` is `14` because it is passed by **reference** into `Twist`, so any changes that happen to `s` in `Twist` will change the value of `s` outside of `Twist`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by value creates a new variable with same content, as with the case when value of `t` is copied in a new variable `a`.

Passing by reference as you did in case of variable `s` which is passed by reference to `b`, this `b` is not a new variable rather it is just another name of your variable `s`.

Whatever operations you perform on `b` will be reflected back on `s`.

Thus when you modify variable `b` in `Twist` function the `s` variable's values also gets modified.